# Postgresql: Select all data between two dates in playframework 1.x

Tags: postgresql, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a postgresql table with data connected to dates. Each row has data and a date, for example:

```
2011-02-03    JOHN   Male   etc
```

I am using playframework. i have created a model named student.java.

and in application.java i have done something like this where firstDate and lastdate are given by user,

```
List (student studentList) = student.find("timestamp BETWEEN 'firstDate' and 'lastDate'").fetch();
```

i want to fetch all the data present between those two dates.

But i know the query is not correct. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
public static final List<Student> findWithDates(Date firstDate, Date lastDate) {
  return find("from Student student where student.date >= ? and student.date <=?",
              firstDate, lastDate).fetch();
}
```